# Ignore Excel warning

Tags: java, excel

I have a question on how to remove a comment in excel that warns you regarding number storing as a text, I simply would like to get rid of this message, went through similar issues but none of those could of helped me getting to the bottom of it.

There is `IgnoredErrorType error = NUMBER_STORED_AS_TEXT;` but I am not sure where my created ENUM can actually be passed to.

Also CellType is deprecated so the following won't work for me

```
public RowBuilder setType(CellType cellType){
        lastCell().setCellType(cellType);
        return this;
    }
```

Another approach i have created dataFormat and have set format to custom "@" means text, and it still wont work and show me the message, even tho the format works for the number if i want Excel to set is as a number

[image]

Thank you